# Using :include and :conditions creates big queries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to fetch all the posts which are commented by specifc user with the eager loading of creator,editor,comments and forum.

Post.rb

```
named_scope :list_of_post {|user_id|
  {
    :include => [:creator,:editor,:comments,:forum],
    :conditions => ["comments.user_id = ?",user_id]
  }
}
```

But this named scope creates a big query instead of small IN queries for creator,editor,comments and forum.

This is happening because of using :include and :conditions together.

Any solutions which returns IN queries for each instead of one big query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using rails 2
You could do that instead of a scope :

```
Post.find(:conditions => {:id => user.comments.map(:post_id)}, :include => [...])
```

When you migrate to rails 3, look at squeel and ransack. It could help you to do your requests easier.

Comment: this will return list of comments not list of posts. And what about condition.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you throw in a `:joins => :comments` in there?  It has to join to do the search, but would explicitly setting the join pull the other tables out of the query?